# Get mean and stddev for each row in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I would like to get mean in each row along with the standard deviation. So that i could find which of the values are out of stddev. the below code gives me stddev.

```
SELECT reccount, 
   STDDEV(reccount) OVER (ORDER BY reccount) "StdDev"
   from
(select 10 as reccount from dual union
select 15 as reccount from dual union
select 20 as reccount from dual union
select 16 as reccount from dual ) A;
```

Avg function if used it gives no group by error.

Is it possible to return avg/mean with each row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below query

```
SELECT reccount, 
   STDDEV(reccount) OVER (ORDER BY reccount) "StdDev",avg(reccount) OVER ()
   from
(select 10 as reccount from dual union
select 15 as reccount from dual union
select 20 as reccount from dual union
select 16 as reccount from dual ) A;
```

[DEMO HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cf707/7)